# Unable to submit form from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I have a JSP file with struts tags.

```
<html:form action="showcart">
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
        <td width="46" align="center" valign="middle"></td>
        <td width="110"></td>
        <td width="31">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="171" class="cart_contents"><span class="heading">Product</span></td>
        <td width="157" class="cart_contents"><span class="heading">Quantity</span></td>
        <td width="181" align="center" valign="middle" class="cart_contents"><span class="heading">Unit Price</span></td>
        <td width="157" class="cart_contents"><span class="heading">Total Price</span></td>
        <td width="222" align="center" valign="middle"></td>
  </tr>
  <%!
        java.util.Map cartList = null;
  %>
  <%
        cartList = (java.util.Map)request.getAttribute("cartList");
        if (null != cartList) {
            for(Object p : cartList.values()) {
                com.pojo.Product product = (com.pojo.Product)p;
  %>
  <tr>
    <td width="46" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=product.getProductid()%>" /></td>
    <td width="110"><img src="images/01.jpg" width="110" height="78" /></td>
    <td width="31">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="171"><span class="heading"><%=product.getProductname()%></span><br /><span class="contents">Serial number:<%=product.getProductid()%></span></td>
    <td width="157" align="center" valign="middle" class="contents">
        <label>
            <input name="textfield2" type="text" value="3" size="5" align="center" onchange="submitForm()" />
        </label>
        <br /></td>
    <td width="181" align="center" valign="middle" class="contents"><span class="price"><%=product.getUnitprice()%></span> </td>
    <td width="157" class="cart_contents"><span class="heading">Total Price</span></td>
    <td width="222" align="center" valign="middle"><span class="blue_contents">Remove</span></td>
  </tr>
  <%
        }
        }
  %>
</table>
<html:submit/>
  </html:form>
```

Whenever the user changes the quantity textfield, a the JS function, submitForm() is invoked. I am using an inline script as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
 {
  document.forms[0].action = "showcart.do?method=updateCart&pcount=2&product=2345";
  document.forms[0].submit();
 }
</script>
```

But, I am getting a JS error saying the form is undefined. Could you tell me where I am wrong?

Waiting for solutions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that HTML correct? Shouldn't you have *<html><form>...*?

Comment: that is a struts tag equivalent to html form.

Comment: Just FYI, using `<%! Map cartlist...` means you have a single map for every JSP instance; if your system has multiple users, it will be very bad. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked perfectly fine for me. Make sure that the javascript code comes after the form. Also make sure there are no javascript errors in your brower's error console. If there are an code after the error will fail to run.